# Does 3D Printing filament meet food safety regulatory requirements? (CE, NSF, etc)

Tags: food-safety, united-states, ce, nsf, european-union

Do filaments that are commonly-used in 3D Printers meet the requirements of Food Safety Regulators in various regions around the world (eg US, EU, Korea, India, etc)?

The most common 3D Printing filaments are:

1. [PLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylactic_acid)
2. [ABS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene)
3. [PETG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate)
4. [TPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoplastic_polyurethane)

Has the NSF or CE made official statements explicitly about the above-listed materials satisfying their regulatory requirements?

Comment: That's an awful lot of different administrations to trawl through. Please limit the question to the ones you are interested in.

Comment: Yeah, as is this question combines like 16 questions in one.  Please narrow it down to one at a time.  As-is, you're asking someone to write a research paper for you.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but I'm looking at nylon filament that meets FDA 21 CFR 177.1395 and
FDA 21 CFR 177.1500. It appears to be about twice as expensive as similar non-compliant filament.

Comment: @vir what type of filament are you "looking at"? Can you please link to it?

Comment: Hmm ya. I post mostly on EE where links to products are discouraged. I just went back through the rules here and didn't see anything forbidding it but I may have missed it, so sorry if this is against the rules but here goes: https://www.mcmaster.com/products/3d-printer-filaments/3d-printer-filaments~/performance~food-safe/

Comment: In case the link goes down, it lists products titled `Nylon Plastic 6/69` and `Nylon Plastic 680`

Comment: See also https://formlabs.com/eu/blog/guide-to-food-safe-3d-printing/

Comment: Can you modify the original question to narrow it down?